# What special configuration is needed to have a domain controller with DNS on a VM in Hyper-V?

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v, windows

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 and it only has the Hyper-V role.
I have a VM also running Windows Server 2012 and it has the Active Directory: Directory Services and DNS ([example.com]) roles. It has been promoted to a domain controller for [example.com].

In the virtualization host I have joined the domain successfully. On a laptop on the network, it can ping my DNS that is inside the VM on the virtualization host. However, it can't resolve anything through the DNS.

I figured it was a firewall issue where the DNS had the firewall allow rule, but the virtualization host did not. I added that, but it didn't fix the issue.

On my laptop, I get "UnKnown can't find [example.com]: No response from server" immediately. There's no time out, it just comes back right away.

What have I overlooked?

Comment: @KenWhite Agreed. I forgot about that. They all look the same sometimes. Too bad there's not an easy way to move your posts or close them yourself without voting.

Comment: Michael, you can flag it for the moderators, and ask them to move it for you.

Comment: Is your laptop pointed toward the correct nameserver (`ipconfig /all`)? Do you get the error when you query the nameserver directly (`nslookup example.com NAMSERVER_IP`)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes it's pointed to the correct nameserver. I do get the same error when using nslookup to query that nameserver directly as well.

Comment: Interestingly enough now. This problem is not present on the machines which are wired into the router, only machines wirelessly connected. Perhaps the wireless switch is behaving differently than the wired one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks indeed like something is filtering wireless access. Can you verify that by changing your laptop from wireless to a wired connection? Run [`nmap`](http://www.nmap.org/) in both cases (wireless as well as wired)

```
nmap -sT -sU -sV -Pn --traceroute -p U:53,T:53 NAMESERVER_IP
```

and compare the results. If the wireless trace stops at your wireless AP/router, you need to check its configuration.

For further analysis you may need to give more information about your network topology.

Comment: It was a NAT issue and after fixing it up it started working after the  midnight maintenance restart. +1 for suggesting nmap!